# The breadcrumbs separator, changing from &gt;?

Tags: breadcrumb

I was wondering is there a way to change the separator in the breadcrumbs from > ? I'm trying to apply a custom style to the breadcrumbs (which by the way, is proving to be a nightmare due to the code already forced onto them, even changing the padding/height is seemingly impossible!) but I'd like to use an image as > instead of the current > tag that's there right.

I've looked through numerous pages of code, including the master page, and cannot find a solution. It's also randomly placed in a span, just like every other item of the breadcrumbs, so it's not possible to just style it out either.

Any help would be fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any html to replace default character.  Simplest approach is to specify pathseparator property in the SiteMapPath control in your custom master page. Alternatively, you can also specify a template for the separator. Check this http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-path-separator-template-in.html

Comment: Wow, that's perfect, thank you! I was looking for something to change, as opposed to something to actually add-in to over-ride the default value. Now have <asp:SiteMapPath PathSeparator="" runat="server"/> and it works perfectly, thank you again!